# Issue with XY-pic

Tags: xy-pic, option-clash

I am trying to use XY-pic for the first time. I copied a bit of headline code from here :
http://zoonek2.free.fr/UNIX/11_xypic/ (sorry, it's in french) and put it in an already existing document. This is my code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}[12pt]
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
\usepackage{geometry}       
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath}      
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}                             
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\newif\ifpdf
\ifpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  \usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage{graphicx}
\fi
\usepackage{dsfont}\let\mathbb\mathds
\usepackage[all,dvips]{xy}
```

(the recent addition being the last two lines). 
When I try to compile and before even adding code for my commutative diagram, I get an error 209 : "clash of options". What should I do ?

Comment: Why are you loading xy twice with different options?

Comment: OK, I think I know what you mean (I'm not very good with preambles' arcane incantations, sorry ;)
\usepackage[all,dvips]{xy} is conflicting with \usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy} ? I just copied 2 different people's code without really understanding it, so...

Comment: Please, show us your diagram code. Put the `12pt` option together the first one on the class.

Comment: OK, so I tried to delete the line \usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
and now I can at least compile. but when I tried a first bit of code, namely

\xymatrix{
    A \ar[r]^f \ar[d]_\phi \ar[rd] & B \ar[d]^\psi \\
    C \ar[r]_g & D
  }
I get a diagram with the arrows missing

Comment: I guess that it is related with the use of the quotes `"`. See on your link the section *Avec Babel, c'est un peu plus compliqué :*

Comment: You can use only one line with 3 options `\usepackage[all,cmtip,dvips]{xy}`. Are you running `latex` or `pdflatex`?

Comment: pdflatex, I think. I copied the code from the section "Avec Babel, c'est un peu plus compliqué". I tried to add a \shorthandoff{;:!?} but I still don't get the arrows

Comment: So use only `all` and your diagram above will work. It is working here. The option `cmtip` is to change the arrow tips.

Comment: `\newif\ifpdf` is simply wrong; just avoid adding the `pdftex` or `dvips` option to packages.

Answer (score 2):

Just to close this one: the problem is loading `xy` twice with different options.

If you really want to load `hyperref` only with `pdflatex`, you have to load the `ifpdf` package: your `\newif\ifpdf` will do nothing except following the false branch. Avoid passing the `pdftex` or `dvips` options to `graphicx`, `hyperref` and `xy`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}[12pt]
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 

\usepackage{geometry}       
\usepackage{amsmath}      
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}                             
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{dsfont}\let\mathbb\mathds

\ifpdf
  \usepackage{hyperref}
\fi
```